# Wrong Answer with Permutation and Combination Example

Tags: math, combinations, permutation, probability, combinatorics

I have below one problem regarding permutation and combination.
I know one solution which I am providing here. But I have another approach to the same problem but it is not giving me same answer as previous one. Can someone tell where am I making mistake here.

**Problem:** From a group of 7 men and 6 women, five persons are to be selected to form a committee so that at least 3 men are there in the committee. In how many ways can it be done?

```
First Answer: 

We can select 5 men ...(option 1)
Number of ways to do this = 7C5

We can select 4 men and 1 woman ...(option 2)
Number of ways to do this = 7C4 × 6C1

We can select 3 men and 2 women ...(option 3)
Number of ways to do this = 7C3 × 6C2

Total number of ways = 7C5 + (7C4 × 6C1) + (7C3 × 6C2)
=  756.
```

Below is my new approach, where I am making mistake but not able to understand it.

```
atleast 3 men should be there. So ways to choose 3 men out of 7 = 7C3
= 35.

Now 2 person has to be selected from remaining 4 men and 6 women. The no of ways it can be done = 10C2 = 45.

Therefore, total no of way = 35*45 = 1575.
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing in second approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will count some ways more than 
Suppose from the 7 men you choose 
M1,M2,M3
and from the remaining 10 person you choose a men M4 and remaining women W1,W2,W3...W6

Now suppose you choose M1,M2,M4 men from the 7 men
and from remaining 10 you choose M3,W1,W2...W6

Now both of this represent the same set and should be counted only once but you are counting them as 2 different ways.Thats why your answer is greater than the expected answer